# ¿Existe alguna funciona para, después de teclear, ejecutar una función?

Tags: javascript, jquery

No me refiero a las funciones **setTimeout o setInterval**, sino alguna función donde yo teclee y ejecute después de dejar de teclear.

**setTimeout o setInterval** dispararan el evento en cada tecla con un retardo y no es lo que quiero.

Algo parecido que encontré fue un **delay**, pero no entiendo como se implementa.

Comment: Por ejemplo si escribis en un input al terminar de escribir y salir de el dando click afuera o presionando tab con onBlur lo podes capturar y hacer que recien ahi se ejecute la funcion: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onblur Algo asi es lo que necesitas? Proba el ejemplo, escribis en el imput y al perder el foco saliendo o dando tab lo convierte a mayuscula

Comment: opciones: `onblur` `onkeyup` `onkeydown`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conseguí mi respuesta en **[esta pregunta en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909441/how-to-delay-the-keyup-handler-until-the-user-stops-typing)**.

**Traducción:**

Utilizo esta pequeña función para el mismo propósito, ejecutando una función después de que el usuario ha dejado de escribir durante un período de tiempo específico o en eventos que se activan a una velocidad alta, como cambiar el tamaño:

```js
function delay(callback, ms) {
  var timer = 0;
  return function() {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
      callback.apply(context, args);
    }, ms || 0);
  };
}

$('#input').keyup(delay(function (e) {
  console.log('¡Tiempo transcurrido!', this.value);
}, 1000));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="input">Intentalo:
<input id="input" type="text" placeholder="Escribe algo aquí ..."/>
</label>
```

Cómo funciona: La función de retardo devolverá una función envuelta que maneja internamente un temporizador individual. En cada ejecución, el temporizador se reinicia con el retardo proporcionado. Si se producen varias ejecuciones antes de que pase este tiempo, el temporizador simplemente se reiniciará y comenzará nuevamente.

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    delay(function(){
      alert('¡Tiempo transcurrido!');
    }, 1000 );
});
```

Cuando el temporizador finalmente termina, la función de devolución de llamada se ejecuta, pasando el contexto y los argumentos originales (en este ejemplo, el objeto de evento jQuery y el elemento DOM como este).

Para algo más sofisticado, eche un vistazo al complemento jQuery Typewatch.

Comment: Hace lo que necesitas, pero ojo, no podes saber cuanto tarda un usuario en escribir algo o  si justo estaba escribiendo y alguien le pregunto algo dejo de escribir y se ejecuta tu funcion, dependiendo lo que necesites que haga tu funcion por ahi se ejecuta antes de tiempo y causa errores o no devuelve el resultado deseado, por eso te comentaba el onBlur porque se ejecuta recien cuando salis de donde estas escribiendo. Si era para un buscador no hay problema a si es algo mas delicado tal vez te genere inconvenientes

Comment: @Juan es precisamente para un buscador.

Comment: Ah ok, en todo caso yo no lo haria por tiempo especificaria que la funcion se ejecute recien cuando el usuario haya escrito 4 caracteres por ejemplo que es el minimo de letras de nombre de un pais si el buscador es de paises etc y dsp un onChange cada vez que suma algo que vuelva a ejecutar la consulta (Obviamente te estoy hablando de un buscador hecho con ajax). Por este motivo es que al subir una pregunta tenes que poner el codigo con el que la estas haciendo y especificar bien que es lo que hace, te hubieran dado la solucion mas rapido

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez te funcione el evento [`keyup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;
  alert('keyup event\n\n' + 'key: ' + keyName);
});
```

Comment: @shadow lo mas cercano a hacer es un **setTimeout o setInterval** pero no es lo que necesito, quiero un retardante después que se deja de teclear.

Comment: Podrías incluir el `setTimeout` dentro del `keyup`.